# Force subclass to override overriden method?

Tags: java, inheritance

Lets say I have three classes:

- Bob
- BobsMom
- BobsKid

Now assume `BobsMom` is from an API, so I do not have control over it. `Bob` extends `BobsMom`, and `BobsKid` extends `Bob`. `Bob` overrides a method in `BobsMom`. How do I force `BobsKid` to override the overriden method in `Bob`.

Comment: Using `abstract` type.

Comment: Then `BobsKid` is-a `Bob` and every `Bob` is-a `BobsMom` and every `BobsKid` is-a `BobsMom` and that's a terribly confusing example of *I'm my own Grandpa* (or Grandma if you prefer). Please post code that demonstrates your actual **practical** question or problem.

Comment: Well, in non OOP language (as in normal English) every Bob comes from a BobsMom and every BobsKid comes from Bob. A case could even be made for this in OOP language has Bob is simply BobsMom, but with some modification, and BobsKid is a modification of these modifications, so from an OOP / family tree perspective it does make send.

Comment: OK, Elliott, I just had to look this up... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw

Comment: made me laugh, and further proves my point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force subclass to override using `abstract` method.

```
  public abstract class Bob extends BobsMom{
      @Override
      abstract void methodToOverride(); // Force subclass to override
  }

  //Subclass
  public class BobKid extends Bob{
      @Override
      void methodToOverride(){

      }
  }
```

Comment: even if the method in BobsMom is not abstract?

Comment: Yes, an abstract class can inherit non-abstract class.